# Prevent flicker while resizing a full height div using resize function

Tags: jquery, resize, window-resize

I use this code in order to create full height divs:

```
$(window).resize(function() {

  var winHeight = $(window).height(); 

  $('#slideshow.royalSlider .item').height(winHeight);

  });

  $(window).trigger('resize');
```

When the browser is resized, div is adjusted to the new height.

However, I've noticed that when this is done, there's a "flicker" when the browser is being resized in which the background is exposed. I've attached the following clip in order to illustrate this behavior.

http://www.giphy.com/gifs/3o7qDWz4yzz4S3Eybu

Is there a way to avoid this?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: If the height always needs to be the window height, it's much better to do this via CSS. Set "height: 100%;" from <body> until the element you need (probably .royalSlider).

Comment: One of the issues that is created by the `.resize()` method is that each incremental pixel that moves causes a `reflow` trigger of the layout internally. The more elements on the page and the more complex the element structure, the more "flickering" that you will see. What you really want to do is only force the draw when you `stop` resizing, not `while` resizing.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Makes sense! How could I force the draw when the resize is stopped?

Comment: You would do something like this: `var resizeTimer;

$(window).on('resize', function(e) {

  clearTimeout(resizeTimer);
  resizeTimer = setTimeout(function() {

    // Run code here, resizing has "stopped"
            
  }, 250);

});`